# JPQL by table name instead of entity name

Tags: jpa, jpql, named-query

I have a new table in my DB which simply aggregates some data which I don't want to hold as a reference in any of my entities. Because of above I don't have an entity of that type in my application. Now the problems starts when I want to create simple query from that table. We use named queries and criteria api in our application as a standard. Since my query is simple and is going to be asked a lot of times the perfect solution would be to use JPQL and named query. But how might I achieve this without having an entity related to this table... As far as I remember there is COLUMN('xxx') expression which can be used to obtain column which isn't used in entity, so maybe there is something similar to do the trick with whole table?

So let me recap, because It's possible that You may have a problem to understand me well :)

```
@Entity
public class Person {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;
}

@Entity
public class Pet {


   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;
}
```

Let's say that besides above two tables I have third one which I don't want to use neither in Pet nor in Person. So:

```
CREATE TABLE ANY_OTHER_TABLE(
  PERSON_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PET_ID BIGINT NOT NULL
);
```

So now question is how should JPQL look like to produce SQL like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ANY_OTHER_TABLE WHERE PET_ID = 1;
```

Comment: As any JPA doc would tell you, JPQL is for querying entities, not tables. You have to have an entity. Anything else and you use non-portable SQL. Can't get simpler.

Comment: A `NamedNativeQuery` could be what you are looking for. If you want to use a JPQL query, you have to create the Entity.

Comment: Yep it could be an option, however I would lose portability in such case :( Anyway thanks for answering :)